# ipyleaflet - how to add on_click color change to the clicked point of GeoData layer

Tags: ipyleaflet

i have added a map with ipyleaflet on my jupyter notebook.
There's a point layer and i want to be able to change the color of the point that i have clicked.

[map ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCSBE.png)

I have tried different methods. I tried calling a node_leaf.style =newstyle, but then it changes color of the whole layer, instead of the specific point

code is here, really appreciate your help!
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2caE.png)